# Java Reference Issue

Tags: java, reference

I'm very new to Java, so I'm sorry if this is a bit too stupid for you. So, I have a class called *Construct* that has an instance variable *previousState*. I have a setter in that class, with the signature *setPreviousState*.

Then, in an other class I set the previous State of a *Construct* object with this code :

```
    ArrayList<Construct> sequence = new ArrayList<Construct>();
    do {
        Construct minimum = priorityQueue.delMin();
        for (Construct neighbor : minimum.neighbors()) {
            neighbor.setPreviousState(minimum);
            priorityQueue.insert(neighbor);
        }
        System.out.println(minimum);
        if (minimum.isGoalState()) {

            // Construct sequence backwards and return it
            sequence.add(minimum);
            while(minimum.previousState() != null) {
                sequence.add(0, minimum.previousState());
            }
            return sequence;
        }
    } while (true);
```

But `while(minimum.previousState() != null)` is an infinite loop because `previousState()` always references the same object. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never change the value of `minimum` in this loop, and it seems that the value of `minimum.previousState()` is also constant for each object [no side affects to method `previousState()`], you might want to add `minimum = minimum.previousState();` to your `while` loop:

```
while(minimum.previousState() != null) {
   sequence.add(0, minimum.previousState());
   minimum = minimum.previousState();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just because you never change what the minimum variable points to in the loop. So you're checking again and again that the same minimum's previousState is not null, without ever changing the minimum's value nor the minimum's previousState.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I don't know how I didn't see that.